# Godot| Как использовать функцию из другого узла?

Tags: godot

Например у меня есть нод "fade" Для перехода,и мне нужно сделать так,чтобы я мог отравить сигнал из другого нода,а "fade" Получил его.Как это реализовать?

Comment: https://ask.godotengine.org/3218/how-to-create-a-custom-signal-in-gdscript

Answer (score 0):

Примерно такой код должен быть у отправителя:

```
extends Node
...
signal my_signal


func _ready():
    ...
    var otherNode = get_node("fade")  # Или как вам надо получать fade.
    otherNode.connect("my_signal", self, "<ИМЯ ФУНКЦИИ ХЭНДЛЕРА>")
    ...

func SomeFunc():
    ...
    emit_signal("my_signal")  # Отправляем сигнал.
    ...
```

и у узла fade:

```
...

func <ИМЯ ФУНКЦИИ ХЭНДЛЕРА>():
    # То что вам надо делать

...
```