# Кастомные сигналы в godot engine

Tags: godot

У меня есть сцены: карта, HUD(интерфейс), объекты. Как сделать, условие, когда игрок на карте подходит к объекту и нажимает на кнопку (из худа). Например, чтобы объект при этом условии удалился

Comment: Без разницы каким способом. Просто я не знаю как с скрипта одной сцены взаимодействовать на другую сцену

Comment: такой вопрос уже был: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1491366/godot-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b0.

Comment: Я только-что дал ответ на токую-же тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1534496/507516